# What is the distinction between an abstract data type and an implementation of that data type

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Distinction between abstract data type and the implementation of that data type

Comment: Not sure that I understand the question, but abstract data type described the API and time and space complexity constraints where as implementation implements that. For example priority queue is an abstract data type and heap is an implementation based on partially sorted array.

Comment: Did you do research on the subject? There are good books on such concepts. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)

Answer (score 1):

An abstract data type like a **queue** supports certain operations.  In this case, insert-at-the-end and remove-from-the-front.  It can be implemented in different ways using different data structures.  One implementation may store elements in an array, while a different implementation may use a linked list.

Similarly, the abstract **Dictionary** data type, could be implemented using a hash table or a binary search tree.

An implementation is an actual class that you can construct or function that you can call.